# Run unit tests in Jenkins / Hudson in automated fashion from dev to build server

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, hudson, automated-tests

We are currently running a Jenkins (Hudson) CI server to build and package our .net web projects and database projects. Everything is working great but I want to start writing unit tests and then only passing the build if the unit tests pass. We are using the built in msbuild task to build the web project. With the following arguments ...

```
MsBuild Version           .NET 4.0
MsBuild Build File    ./WebProjectFolder/WebProject.csproj  
Command Line Arguments    ./target:Rebuild /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=True;PackageLocation=".\obj\Release\WebProject.zip";PackageAsSingleFile=True
```

We need to run automated tests over our code that run automatically when we build on our machines (post build event possibly) but also run when Jenkins does a build for that project.

If you run it like this it doesn't build the unit tests project because the web project doesn't reference the test project. The test project would reference the web project but I'm pretty sure that would be butchering our automated builds as they exist primarily to build and package our deployments. Running these tests should be a step in that automated build and package process.

### Options ...

1. Create two Jenkins jobs. one to run the tests ... if the tests pass another build is triggered which builds and packages the web project. Put the post build event on the test project.
2. Build the solution instead of the project (make sure the solution contains the required tests) and put post build events on any test projects that would run the nunit console to run the tests. Then use the command line to copy all the required files from each of the bin and content directories into a package.
3. Just build the test project in jenkins instead of the web project in jenkins. The test project would reference the web project (depending on what you're testing) and build it.

### Problems ...

1. There's two jobs and not one. Two things to debug not one. One to see if the tests passed and one to build and compile the web project. The tests could pass but the build could fail if its something that isn't used by what you're testing ...
2. This requires us to know exactly what goes into the build. Right now msbuild does it all for us. If you have multiple teams working on a project everytime an extra folder is created you have to worry about the possibly brittle command line statements.
3. This seems like a corruption of our main purpose here. The tests should be a step in this process not the overriding most important thing in this process. I'm also not 100% sure that a triggered build is the same as a normal build does it do all the same things as a normal build. Move all the correct files in the same way move them all into the same directories etc.

### Initial problem.

We want to run our tests whenever our main project is built. But adding a post build event to the web project that runs against the test project doesn't work because the web project doesn't reference the test project and won't trigger a build of this project. I could go on ... but that's enough ...

We've spent about a week trying to make this work nicely but haven't succeeded. Feel free to edit this if you feel you can get a better response ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Jenkins/Hudson, it's quite ok to have many jobs. some for doing compilation triggered version control changes, some for running (unit) tests triggered by successful builds, some for doing more tests (integeration) trigered by successful earlier tests, some for deploying, triggered by successfully passing all tests.

Look at plugins like join, build pipeline, parametrized trigger and more to help out with this.

This will also allow things to happen in parallel, by using multiple nodes. Trying to cram everything in one job is not the way to go.